# Is there a tool for synonymous recoding of DNA sequences?

Tags: r, bioconductor, mutations, synonymous-mutations

I've got a DNA sequence that I'd like to make synonymous mutations throughout, thereby preserving the amino acid sequence. Does anyone know of a tool to achieve this

Comment: I don't but it wouldn't it be easier to write one?  The other issue is that context would be useful, it is fairly common to consider synonymous mutations in fitness, particularly cancers and it would make sense to construct a null distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bioconductor package named `synmut` which does just that.
Apparently, it can take codon usage into account when generating synonymous mutations.

Copy pasting an example that matches your use case from [the official doc](https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.11/bioc/vignettes/SynMut/inst/doc/SynMut.html):

```r
library("SynMut")
filepath.fasta <- system.file("extdata", "example.fasta", package = "SynMut")
filepath.csv <- system.file("extdata", "target_regions.csv", package = "SynMut")
region <- read.csv(filepath.csv)
rgd.seq <- input_seq(filepath.fasta, region)
mut.seq <- codon_random(rgd.seq, keep = TRUE)
Biostrings::writeXStringSet(get_dna(mut.seq), "rgd.fasta")
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, that package works well

Answer (score 0):

[DNA Chisel](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/DnaChisel/) can introduce synonymous mutations into your sequence.
Annotate the coding sequence with the [@cds constraint](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/DnaChisel/genbank/genbank_api.html#indicating-coding-sequences) and the [~change objective](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/DnaChisel/genbank/genbank_api.html#forcing-changes).

Additionally, you may also optimize the codon usage to match your species with [~match_codon_usage](https://edinburgh-genome-foundry.github.io/DnaChisel/genbank/genbank_api.html#codon-optimization) or one of the other options.

A web interface is also provided at EGF CUBA (Collection of Useful Biological Apps): [Sculpt a Sequence](https://cuba.genomefoundry.org/sculpt_a_sequence)

*Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of DNA Chisel*